# Time to receive foreign dividends (SET) to N. America

Tags: stocks, canada, dividends, thailand

Is there an expected time to receive foreign dividends? It seems to take weeks or longer to receive dividends from stocks on the SET exchange.

Granted they have to do a currency conversion and take off withholding taxes, but surely that should be a matter of a few days if not instantaneous?